# Terminal color codes not working in bash on my mac

Tags: bash

According to [this page](http://bruxy.regnet.cz/web/linux/EN/bash-on-fire/), the following should output colorized characters:

```
$ B=(' ' '\E[0;31m.' '\E[0;31m:' '\E[1;31m+' '\E[0;33m+' '\E[1;33mU' '\E[1;33mW');
$ echo -e ${B[*]}
```

Instead, for me on Mac OS X (GNU bash, 4.4.0), it just echoes back literally:

```
\E[0;31m. \E[0;31m: \E[1;31m+ \E[0;33m+ \E[1;33mU \E[1;33mW
```

Do I need to enable / disable some setting to make this work?

Comment: works for me (macOS + bash4.4). what's the output of `type echo` on your system?

Comment: @pynexj sorry i misread your comment earlier.  the answer is it outputs `echo is a shell builtin`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what's the real problem but you can use Bash's `$'...'` syntax for the <kbd>ESC</kbd> char:

```
[STEP 101] $ B=($'\e[0;31m.' $'\e[0;31m:' $'\e[1;31m+' $'\e[0;33m+' $'\e[1;33mU' $'\e[1;33mW')
[STEP 102] $ echo ${B[@]}
. : + + U W
```

[image]

Another option is use `printf` which is more consistent:

```
[STEP 104] $ printf '\e[1;31mhello\e[0m\n'
hello
```

[image]

Comment: **NOTE:** Just checked and confirmed that even the old *bash-2.05b*'s `$'...'` and `printf` also support `\e`.

Answer (score 2):

For licensing reasons, the version of Bash installed by default on macOS is version 3, even though version 4 has been around since 2009.  The `\E` escape sequence was apparently introduced in version 4 or one of its minor versions, and thus it does not work in version 3.  However, `\E` is apparently just a synonym for `\e`, which does work in v3, and so changing `\E` to `\e` in your code snippet should allow it to work.

Comment: That didn't work.  Also, note per my original post that running `bash --version` returns `GNU bash, version 4.4.0(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0)...`

Comment: `bash --version` may be not using the same bash as you're using. so try `echo $BASH_VERSION` in the bash you're running.

Comment: @jwodder, what kind of licensing reasons macOS is not using the latest bash?

Comment: @pynexj As far as I understand it, Apple declines to ship anything that is licenced under GPLv3 as it conflicts with their policies and aims. You are at liberty to install GPLv3 software yourself, e.g. using the **homebrew** package manager.

Comment: You were right, `$BASH_VERSION` is `3.2.57(1)-release`.  How is it possible that `bash --version` does not return the one I'm using?  Also, any other suggestions since using `\e` did not solve it?

Comment: `type -all bash` should reveal two installs (probably one from Homebrew) and the one you get as your login shell is probably the system one, defined by your login settings (traditionally `/etc/passwd`; not where I can check if Apple imposes something else on top or around this).

Comment: Unless your target is specifically to explore how `echo -e` still creates portability problems after 20+ years, the core answer here should be *use `printf`*